# atop: how to compress or hide the processors at top on large machines?

Tags: atop

Header lists all CPUs/cores and keeps re-sizing as I go back in time with <kbd>t</kbd> and <kbd>T</kbd>. I read though the help and tried searching.

How to hide that header?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hidden in the man page at line 404. Use <kbd>l</kbd> and define each header line. In short, if you only want to see one header line for CPU you would type <kbd>l</kbd> (that's a lower case <kbd>L</kbd>) then <kbd>1</kbd> (the number one) and hit enter for the other summary statistics. Here's the man page output.

```
 l    Limit the number of system level lines for the counters per-cpu, the active disks and
            the  network  interfaces.   By default lines are shown of all CPUs, disks and network
            interfaces which have been active during the last interval.  Limiting these lines can
            be  useful  on systems with huge number CPUs, disks or interfaces in order to be able
            to run atop on a screen/window with e.g. only 24 lines.
```